# How to create a select clause using a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql statement:

```sql
WITH
subquery AS (
    select distinct id from a_table where some_field in (1,2,)
)
select id from another_table where id in subquery;
```

### Edit

JOIN is not an option (this is just a reduced example of a bigger query)

But that obviously does not work. The `id` field exists in both tables (with a different name, but values are the same: numeric ids). Basically what I want to do is filter by the result of the subquery, like a kind of intersection.

Any idea how to write that query in a correct way?

Comment: `... IN (SELECT id FROM subquery) ...` But I would recommend to rewrite it as a `JOIN`.

Comment: But does that line execute the select for every row on `another_table`? I'm aware of the JOIN option, but that's not possible (that just a reduced example of another query).

Comment: Depends on what the optimizer "thinks" is best. But usually no. The CTE might even be materialized.

Comment: Oh great! Can you post that as an answer? :D

Comment: For a mere lookup I wouldn't join, but use `IN` or `EXISTS`. You only got the syntax wrong. sticky bit's IN clause should work just fine for you.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is not necessary in your query, but it may be in your bigger query for some reason of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery for the second operand of `IN` that `SELECT`s from the CTE.

```
... IN (SELECT id FROM subquery) ...
```

But I would recommend to rewrite it as a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to join on ID and then filter on the Where clause?

```
select a.id
  from a.table 
  inner join b.table on a.id = b.id
 where b.column in (1,2)
```

Comment: I cannot use JOIN, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the `id` from `another_table` you can use `exists`

```
with s as (
    select id 
    from a_table 
    where some_field in (1,2)
)
select id 
from another_table t
where exists ( select * from s where s.id=t.id )
```

But the CTE is really redundant since all you are doing is

```
select id 
from another_table t
where exists (
    select * from a_table a where a.id=t.id and a.some_field in (1,2)
)
```